# How to randomly create an outlier dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, outliers

I am trying to create an outlier dataset, which has 8 columns, some columns contain categorical value, and others contain positive numerical value. And this data contains only two type of datapoint: normal datapoint and outlier.

And i wonder do you know any tools or libraries or some ways that can help me to create this type of dataset automatically. I hear that numpy has tools to generate standard distribution but i think it can't create categorical value.

And like every times, thank you so much for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreword: you should ask yourself a very important question: what is an outlier according to you and try to simulate those afterwards. You can find rough guidelines below:

### Numerical values

You could easily do it by creating one dataset with some predefined distribution (say standard normal with mean `0` and variance of `1`) and create some data points with it (say `10_000`). Other one would come from another distribution (even Gaussian but different mean, variance) and say `50` points being outliers.

### Categorical values

Depending on the size of possible categorical values and whether you want both outliers and non-outliers data to be within some range.

#### Categorical values same range

Say, categorical values are within `[0, 10]`. So you generate them with numpy's `np.random.randint` on the whole spectrum, and, say, for 5 columns, so you would get for one example something along the lines of:

```
[1, 4, 7, 9, 3]
```

Now outliers could have narrower values contained within `[0, 10]`, say `[7,9]`, so their values could be:

```
[7, 7, 8, 9, 8]
```

Given that combination it should be found as an outlier (with some false positives of course as `[0, 10]` could create something similar in principal).

#### Categorical values different range

This case is simpler; just use different range and you can be sure no data point will have those values in non-outlier data.

### Summary

All in all, you can mix those approaches and vary the degree to make the outlier algorithm's task harder (similar data generating processes) or simpler (features differ greatly between those two).

It should be pretty easy to parametrize above and create a function with varying degree of easness. Unless you need something more complicated don't go for a library (of course you could make the whole idea way more complicated).

Comment: It's very detail. Thank you so much, sir.